# Flash Is Not Updating

Tags: flash

Recently I have been having problems with my "Adobe Flash plug-in" from the Ubuntu Software Centre. When I go to view YouTube for example, I get an error in my browser saying the following:

```
Firefox has prevented the outdated plugin "Adobe Flash" from running on
www.youtube.com
```

I've checked for updates using the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

So I tried to update the plug-in via the Firefox browser. So I went to the URL "about:addons" and clicked on the Plugins section on the left. When I click on the Adobe Flash plugin, it says

```
Shockwave Flash is known to be vulnerable and should be updated.  Update Now
```

Where the "Update Now" part is a hyperlink to the following page:
https://blocklist.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked/p948

On this page there is no information about how to update it. So I am stuck. How do I update my flash plugin properly without trying to download the latest version directly from the Adbobe website?

Comment: Can't you update it from the [plugin checker](http://www.mozilla.com/plugincheck/)? By the way, what version do you have installed?

Comment: The plugin checker refers me to the following link
https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
This appears to just be a complete new install rather than updating it, so I don't think that's what I need to do here.